# How to edit an email address in the 'to' field in the stock mail app (iOS14)?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email

Sometimes I have an email address in the 'to' field of a mail, that has perhaps been launched from safari, and I would like to edit it
e.g.

```
before: info@salesmonkeys.com
after: support@salesmonkeys.com
```

however, there seems to be no way to do this at all.
It just seems to exist as an uneditable object.
If you try and drag it down to the body it just makes a VCF file.
If you hold on it, it just allows you to de/select it as an recipient.

surely there is a way to quickly do this (and without having to create a new contact!)
?